# git not adding a new file on diff?

Tags: git

I have some code changes that I'd like to send to someone via a diff file, the changes involved renaming a file's extension (so it looks like a file's been added and a new one added). `git status` shows me the following:

```
On branch master
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.

Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

        new file:   source/blender/blenkernel/intern/mesh_evaluate.cc

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add/rm <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

        modified:   source/blender/blenkernel/CMakeLists.txt
        deleted:    source/blender/blenkernel/intern/mesh_evaluate.c
        modified:   source/blender/blenlib/BLI_linklist_stack.h
```

But when I do something like `git diff > foo.txt`, I don't see the "new" file in there at all. Is there something else I need to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's easier to use [`format-patch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-format-patch)

```
git commit -m 'message describing the change'
git format-patch -1 HEAD
```

It will generate numbered patch files, such as `0001-message-describing-the-change.patch`, which you can then send to your colleague.

Answer (score 2):

The new file is already staged for commit, that's why it doesn't appear in the output of `git diff`.

On the other hand, if it weren't added to the staging area, Git wouldn't know about it at all and it wouldn't be shown in `git diff` either.

The solution is to add the "empty" file to staging, but not its contents. This can be done with

```
git add -N source/blender/blenkernel/intern/mesh_evaluate.cc
```

(Before, you need to remove it from the staging area again with `git reset`.)

Answer (score 2):

`git diff` only shows unstaged changes. This means that it will not show changed files that you added to the staging area using `git add`.

If you want the diff to include files from the staging area, you can use `git diff HEAD` instead of `git diff`. This shows the difference to `HEAD` (the currently checked out commit) that includes staged changes.

If it is added to the staging area, you can view the diff using `git diff HEAD`.

However, as [knittl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/112968/knittl) meantioned in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/112968/knittl), `git format-patch` (or similar tools) is better for sending changes/patches to someone else (make sure to follow the guidelines of the maintainer regarding submitting patches).

Answer (score 1):

`git diff` will only show changes to **tracked** files that are not already staged for commit.

A new file is not tracked yet, so not visible.

You need to add it first using `git add newfile.txt`.

But then it would also be immediately staged, to have `git diff` show those changes you can use `git diff --cached`. Or dan1st s other answer which is better imo: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68107302/7362396